# PHP or HTML Form Validation

Tags: php, html, validation

I want to validate an HTML form in either HTML or PHP. By validate, I mean ensuring there is at least 1 character of text entered into each of the 2 textboxes. And either only alpha numeric characters entered, or have something that ensures that any punctuation doesn't end up with "/" before it.

At the moment my form is made up of 2 php pages (copied below), and then posted to a txt file.

I'm either after some (very basic) instructions on how to do it, or suggestions on my script below.

```
//HTML
<form style="" method="post" action="addtopic2.php">
Topic:<input name="topic" id="topicbox" maxlength="100" type="text"><br>
Outline: <textarea input wrap="nowrap" rows="10" cols="120" 
name="outline"></textarea>    
<br><input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
//HTML

<?php
$t = "Topic:";
$o = "Outline:";

$topic = $_POST['topic'];
$outline = $_POST['outline'];

$data = "$t $topic | $o $outline |\n";

$fh = fopen("users.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, $data); 
fclose($fh); 
?>
```

//ATTEMPTED TO USE FOLLOWING,  BUT DOESNT SEEM TO WORK WHEN INSERTING INTO EITHER PAGES.

```
<?php
if($_POST['Submit'] == "submit")
{
  $errorMessage = "";
  if(empty($_POST['topic']))
  {
$errorMessage .= "<li>A topic needs to be entered</li>";
  }
  if(empty($_POST['outline']))
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>An outline needs to be entered</li>";
  }
  $vartopic = $_POST['formtopic'];
  $varoutline = $_POST['formoutline'];
  if(!empty($errorMessage))
  {
    echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
        echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
  }
}
?>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['topic']) && isset($_POST['outline'])) {
     $topic = trim($_POST['topic']);
    $outline = trim($_POST['outline']);
}
else {
  echo '<p>Fill the form</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: For the record, I actually spent quite a bit of time researching this. All the suggestions i found are either in Javascript. Or as above, but dont work and Im not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$file = "users.txt";
$errorMessage = array ();

if ($_POST ['Submit'] == "submit") {
    if (empty ( $_POST ['topic'] )) {
        $errorMessage [] = "A topic needs to be entered<";
    }
    if (empty ( $_POST ['outline'] )) {
        $errorMessage [] = "An outline needs to be entered";
    }

    if (count ( $errorMessage ) == 0) {
        $data = $_POST ['topic'] . "|" . $_POST ['outline'] . "\n";
        $fh = fopen ( $file, "a" );
        fwrite ( $fh, $data );
        fclose ( $fh );
    } else {
        print ("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n") ;
        print ("<ul>") ;
        foreach ( $errorMessage as $error ) {
            print "<li>" . $error . "<li>";
        }
        print ("</ul>") ;
    }
}

// To Read Your File

$content = file ( $file );
print ("<p>File Details</p>\n") ;
foreach ( $content as $info ) {
    list ( $topic, $outline ) = explode ( "|", $info );
    print ("<ul>") ;
    print "<li>Topic: " . $topic . "<li>";
    print "<li>Outline:" . $outline . "<li>";
    print ("</ul>") ;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I've been looking at this screen for too long, and not taking that much in. Where should these scripts go?  1st or 2nd page, before or after the other scripts I have? And what's the purpose of the second script you've provided.

Comment: I've tried the fist script, and it does the same thing as all other scripts I've tried. Nothing. You can still leave all the text fields emppty and it will be accepted.

Comment: I wanted to know how to validate a form, so that if no text is entered into the form, an error appears that says the user needs to complete the fields.

Comment: Eg, if text box 1 = empty, and/or text box 2 = empty, the form is not submitted, and an error message says please complete text box 1 or 2.  In Javascript its easy, but I cant get it to work in PHP

Comment: That is exactly what i did  ... are you not seeing any error displayed ??? if you are not than you sure `$_POST ['Submit'] == "submit"` is correct ?? because if that statement is not correct the script would not run

Comment: ok look at the php and tell me .. which line you don't understand

Comment: There is no error message. If I leave both text boxes empty, and push submit, it appears to submit, and takes me to the 2nd page. In the text form, it show the form has been submitted (with 2 empty text fields), plus the timestamp. I took the timestamp out of my code, because I didnt think it is relevant - but maybe it is?

Comment: Oh ok ... why don't you add your full code .. including the one you are using to send user to another page... may be in can help .. if its long you are put it as pastebin

Comment: <html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>Add Topic</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="StylesheetSpare.css"
 type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>text</h1>
<h2>text</h2>

<form style="" method="post" action="addtopic2.php">
Topic:<input name="topic" id="topicbox" maxlength="100" type="text"><br>
Outline: <textarea input wrap="nowrap" rows="10" cols="120" name="outline"></textarea><br><br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>

<p><a href="index.html">Return to Home Page</a><br>
</body></html>

Comment: <?php
$b = time (); 
$c = date("g:i:s A D, F jS Y",$b);
print "Topic and Outline Submitted at $c";

$t = "Topic:";
$o = "Outline:";
$d = "Time Date:";

print "<p>";

$topic = $_POST['topic'];
$outline = $_POST['outline'];

$data = "$t $topic | $o $outline | $d $c |\n";

$fh = fopen("users.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, $data); 
fclose($fh); 
?>

Comment: Not sure if that is readable. Page 1 is first, then Page 2. I couldnt fit it all in, but the rest is just standard HTML text on both pages (but saved as a .php text file). No other forms or anything else but text, separate page link and text headers

Answer (score 0):

Try this (single file) solution:

```
<form style="" method="post">

    Topic:<input name="topic" id="topicbox" maxlength="100" type="text" value='<?= $_REQUEST['topic'] ?>><br>
    Outline: <textarea input wrap="nowrap" rows="10" cols="120" name="outline"><?= $_REQUEST['outline'] ?></textarea>
    <p/>
    <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">

</form>

<?php

    if ($_REQUEST['submit'] !== 'submit')
    {
        exit;
    }

    if ($_REQUEST['topic'] == '')
    {
        echo "<p>Missing Topic.</p>\n";
        exit;
    }

    if ($_REQUEST['outline'] == '')
    {
        echo "<p>Missing Outline.</p>\n";
        exit;
    }

    $t = "Topic:";
    $o = "Outline:";

    $topic = $_POST['topic'];
    $outline = $_POST['outline'];

    $data = "$t $topic | $o $outline |\n";

    $fh = fopen("users.txt", "a");
    fwrite($fh, $data); 
    fclose($fh); 
?>
```